# Delete dynamic cell in GetCell method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios, custom-cell

I am trying trying to remove a cell from the UITableView if the image for the cell is a bad image. Basically my code does a threadPool call for each cell's image to make the flow of binding the data as a user scroll smooth as so inside the GetCell method:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
 //other stuff
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RetrieveImage),(object)cell);
}
```

within that asynchronous method I call the cell.imageUrl property and bind it to an NSData object as so:

```
NSData data = NSData.FromUrl(nsUrl); //nsUrl is cell.imageUrl
```

From there I know that if **data==null** then there was a problem retrieving the image so I want to remove it. What I currently do is set the hidden property to true, but this leaves a blank space. I want to remove the cell entirety so the user won't even know it existed.
I can't set the cell height to 0 because I don't know if the imageUrl is bad until that indexrowpath initiates getcell call. I don't want to just check all images from the data thats binded to the UITableView because that would be a big performance hit since it can be easily a hundred items. I am currently grabbing the items from a webservice that gives me the first 200 items.
How can I remove the cell altogther **if the data==null**  example

```
NSUrl nsUrl = new NSUrl(cell.imageUrl);
NSData data = NSData.FromUrl(nsUrl);
if (data != null) {
     InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
    cell.imgImage = new UIImage (data);
    //cell.imgImage.SizeToFit();
});
 } else {
   //I tried the below line but it does't work, I have a cell.index property that I set in the getCell method
   _data.RemoveAt(cell.Index);//_data is the list of items that are binded to the uitableview
    InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
    //cell.Hidden = true;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You remove cells by removing them from your source and then you let `UITableView` know that the source has changed by calling `ReloadData().` This will trigger the refresh process. `UITableView` will ask your source how many rows there are and because you removed one row from your data, the cell representing that row will be gone.
However `ReloadData()` will reload your entire table. There is a methods which allows you to remove cells specifically, named `DeleteRows().` You can find an example here at [Xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_4_-_editing).

When deleting rows it is important that you update your model first, then update the UI.

Alternatively, I recommend you to check out [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) which allows interaction with UITableView in a more direct way. It also includes support for lazy loading images.